# save the values of the input in case of error in node.js

Tags: node.js, validation

when there is a validation error the page is reloaded and rendered with the error message, but all fields are cleaned, how can I do so that when there is an error the fields are not cleaned?

```
app.post('/email', (req, res, next)=>{

req.checkBody("email", "ingrese un correo valido").isEmail();
req.checkBody("name", "solo letras en el campo nombre").isAlpha();

var errors = req.validationErrors();

if(errors){
    res.render('index', {errors: errors});
    return;
}else{
       // normal processing
}

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass to the template also the inputs, so the line should be something like`res.render('index', {errors: errors, inputs: inputs});` and then in the template render the page according to which variables you have

Comment: thanks for the help, but could you give me an example of how it would be represented in the view

Comment: Supposing that 'email' and 'name' are two inputs, you just need to check if the variables you use to pass the inputs are valued and if yes write the value in the `value` option of the relevant field. Without a look at the code and without knowing which template engine you are using, I can nothing more...